# Unbound Variable on Function Name

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a program in Lisp(common lisp dialect)..
I want the program to count the number of sublists in a list..
This is what I have written till now:

```
(defun llength (L)
      (cond 
          ((null L)   0)    
          ((list (first L)) (progn (+ (llength (first L)) 1) (llength (rest L))))    
          ((atom (first L)) (llength (rest L)))
      )
)
```

The function returns the error "Unbound variable: LLENGTH" and I don't understand why or how I can fix it..
Any suggestions ?

Comment: yes, please reformat the code, so it is readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun llength (list)
  (cond 
    ((null list) 0)
    ((listp (first list))
     ;; 1 + the count of any sub-lists in this sub-list + the 
     ;; count of any sub-lists in the rest of the list.
     (+ 1 (llength (first list))
        (llength (rest list))))
    (t (llength (rest list)))))
```

Test:

```
> (llength '(1 2 3 4))
0
> (llength '(1 2 (3 4)))
1
> (llength '(1 2 (3 (4))))
2
> (llength '(1 2 (3 4) (5 6) (7 8) (9 (10 (11)))))
6
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple errors in your code.

First of all, `list` function *creates new list*, not checking if it is a list. The function you need is `listp` - "p" at the end means "predicate".

Second, `(progn (+ (llength (first L)) 1) (llength (rest L))` will not increase counter. `progn` performs expressions one by one and returns **result of the last** expression, other results are just thrown out. `progn` is there mostly for side effects. What you actually need is addition of all three components: 1 to indicate one found list, result of applying function to the first element and result for applying to the rest. So, this line must be:

```
((listp (first L)) (+ (llength (first L)) (llength (rest L)) 1))
```

More errors may exist, please, be careful to indent code correctly - it really helps to reduce them.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function with the `(defun function name (parameters))` call you must then call the function by typing:

```
(function name (parameters))
```

Perhaps you were simply typing:

```
function name (parameters)
```

Doing this will get you the error you are receiving so be sure to encompass your whole statement in parenthesis.